# Android licensing extra data

Tags: android, android-lvl

the android licensing documentation talk about three extra parameters (GT, GR and VT). Are those customizable through the developer market account, when the application is published? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not customizable by yourself and the will be sent by Google depending on various situations as described here:

[LVL - Extras](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#extras)